# Is it possible to get this result?

Tags: probability, bayesian, chain-rule

I'm trying to get this result:

$P(Y,\theta \mid D,X) = P(Y \mid \theta, D,X) P(\theta | D)$

But I can't get exactly $P(Y \mid \theta, D,X) P(\theta | D)$ in the right side of the equation. What I get is:

$P(Y,\theta \mid D, X)=\frac{P(Y, \theta, D, X)}{P(D, X)}=\frac{P(Y \mid \theta, D, X) P(\theta \mid D, X)P(D, X)}{P(D, X)}=P(Y \mid \theta, D, X) P(\theta \mid D, X)$

Is it possible to get rid of the $X$ in $P(\theta \mid D,X)$

Comment: In general, no. What's the context of the problem? Are you working with a specific model? If you can prove that $\theta$ is conditionally independent of $X$ given $D$, then you can get rid of the $X$ in $P(\theta|D,X)$.

Comment: In the context of beyesian prediction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference)  to use the posterior predictive distribution directly to make prediction about the label $Y$ of a test sample with features $X$.

Comment: Assuming that $P(\theta \mid D, X) = P(\theta \mid D)$ does the trick. But is it correct in this context?

Comment: What are $\theta$ and $D$?

Comment: $D$ is my data. $\theta$ is a parameter of a distribution (like $P$ in the binomial distribution https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_binomial) or a model. $Y$ is my prediction about a label. $X$ represents features.

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with Bayesian stats (beyond the basics), so I'm trying to get a clear idea of what you are asking. Would I be correct in treating features as the parameters of the prior distribution of $\theta$?

Comment: No, $\theta$ follows a beta distribution, $P(\theta) = \frac{\theta^{\alpha - 1}(1 - \theta)^{\beta - 1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)}$. $B(\alpha, \beta)$ is a normalization constant to make sure everything sums to 1.

Comment: Then I would suspect that you do have conditional independence. However, I'm not really the best person to answer this question for you. Good luck!